# Is it smart to use clustering at the beginning of your NodeJS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express, worker

So you probably know that you can enhance your NodeJS app performance using clustering. For the curious, the recommended number of instances is equal to the number of your cores. My question is: What are the downsides if I use clustering at the beginning of my app, making several server instances from the start? I only found the disadvantages of creating a greater number of instances than the number of your cores.

Comment: Well, for one, you now have a distributed app with all of the pitfalls of a distributed app – e.g. you'll need to think about whether you'll need locks for some of your transactions, or whether you can be absolutely certain there's only ever one reader/writer.

Comment: Are you referring to the critical section problem? (The critical section problem is used to design a protocol followed by a group of processes so that when one process has entered its critical section, no other process is allowed to execute in its critical section)